# How can I make a column in a dataframe from a list of lists?

Tags: r

I want to create a data frame with mydates and val. mydates is a list of lists of dates, and I want the dataframe column to be a list for each row. Is this possible? I keep getting an error saying that the row lengths are different, but when I check using length(), both mydate and vals are returning 100.

```
end_date <- as.Date('2010-03-07')   

mydate <- list()

for(i in 1:100){
  dates <- sample(1:40,1)
  mydate[[i]] <- list(as.Date(sample( as.numeric(start_date): as.numeric(end_date), dates, 
                                     replace = T), 
                             origin = '1970-01-01'))
}

vals <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace=T)
data.frame(mydate, vals)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issue in your approach. You can try the following.

```
start_date <- as.Date('2010-01-01')  #--- (1)  
end_date <- as.Date('2010-03-07')   

mydate <- vector('list', 100) #--- (2)

for(i in 1:100){
  dates <- sample(1:40,1)
  mydate[[i]] <- sample(seq(start_date, end_date, by = '1 day'), 
                        dates, replace = TRUE) #--- (3)
}
vals <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(vals)
df$mydate <- mydate #--- (4)
```

(1)  - `start_date` was missing in your code. I chose an arbitrary `start_date`, please correct it as per your data.

(2) - Instead of using `list()`, initialise an empty list with fixed length when you already know it's length. It is very efficient.

(3) - You can create sequence of dates directly instead of creating sequence of numbers and then converting it into date.

(4) - You cannot add a list of vectors in `data.frame` call, add it separately.

Comment: When I run this, the dates are no longer in date format. Is there a way to do this while keeping the format as dates?

Comment: @assemblysos123 The numbers are how they are displayed, see the actual values by doing `df$mydate[[1]]` and `df$mydate[[2]]`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to work with `tibbles` instead of `data.frames`.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(mydate = flatten(mydate), vals = vals)
```

`x` is then not a data.frame but a `tibble`. You can convert `x` into a data.frame if you want:

```
x2 <- as.data.frame(x)
```